# Looping over two columns and copy rows only when items are matching

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have two sheets with the following datasets :

Sheet 1:

```
05/12/2016  366505  3299193 217374
06/12/2016  345886  3328374 219832
07/12/2016  328152  3348070 221501
08/12/2016  171627  3308919 222948
09/12/2016  338694  3344380 225481
```

Sheet 2:

```
05/12/2016  366505  3299193 217374
06/12/2016  345886  3328374 219832
07/12/2016  328152  3348070 221501
08/12/2016  blank   blank   blank
09/12/2016  blank   blank   blank
```

I would like to be able to loop through each column of the sheet 1 
then compare with each column of the sheet 2 and for each date missing, I would like to copy the corresponding data in Sheet 2.

I've been able to wrote this until now, but I'm not sure of the logic I should use and how I should organise my code :

```
function myFunction() {

var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Sheet2");

var date1 = sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues(); 
var date2 = sheet2.getRange(2, 1, sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();


  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getLastRow()

  for (var i = 0; i < date1.length; i++){
      var list1 = date1[i][0];
      var list2 = date2[i][0];
  if ( //comparison between list1 and list 2 here ){
  var data1 = sheet1.getRange(1,2).getValue();
  var data2 = sheet1.getRange(1,3).getValue();
  var data3 = sheet1.getRange(1,4).getValue();
  sheet2.getRange(i+1, 1,sheet1.getLastRow(), sheet1.getLastColumn()).appendRow([data1,data2,data3]);}

}
```

edit #1: I rewrite most of my question. It wasn't clear at all. I hope it's better now !

Comment: Are missing rows only at the end? If not, then you need to keep track of your "current row on sheet 2" separately.

e.g.
5/12/2016
6/12/2016
7/12/2016
against
5/12/2016
7/12/2016
wouldn't match because sheet1 has 7/12/2016 on its third row, while sheet 2 has 7/12/2016 on its second row.

Comment: Do you expect them to be ordered? or can any date be anywhere in the other sheet?

Comment: It will be always at the end and always ordered. In other words, the only possible differences between the date column on sheet 1 and 2 are the missing date at the end.

Comment: Do you need the date for the appended row? "list2"? (What are you seeing when it's not working?)

Comment: Sorry I had a mistake in my question it should be clearer now.

Comment: Now your if statement is incorrect

Comment: Yes. I don't know which logic should I used. I think that I need to compare each cell and copy the data if the cell from sheet2 is empty but It doesn't sound very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified @SimonBreton Code to reduce overhead operation. Details of modification are commented in the code. In short don't use getValue/s and setValue/s repeatedly, better to get all the data/date at once to an array, modify that array. Once all the modification is done set values using the array once at the end.

```
function myFunction() {

var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Sheet2");
//Get all the values as array rather then using getValues repeatedly. 
//Note: also gave num of columns as 3, to get values for all three columns/
var date1 = sheet1.getRange(1, 2, sheet1.getLastRow(),3).getValues(); //getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
var date2 = sheet2.getRange(1, 2, sheet1.getLastRow(),3).getValues();

// You can compare and add data to your date2 array
  for (var i = 0; i < date1.length; i++){
      test = date1[i][0]
      if(i < date2.length){  // make sure you dont exceed the length of the second array
       test1 = date2[i][0]
       if (test != test1 ) {
        date2[i] = date1[i] // Note this is pass by reference, so if you modify date1 within this code. date2 will be also be modified. 
       }
      } 
      else { //if you have more data in date1 use push to add elements to the end
       date2.push(date1[i])
      }
  }
// Write the data only once at the end with the update date2 array.
sheet2.getRange(1,2,date2.length,date2[0].length).setValues(date2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a working code here :

```
function myFunction() {

var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Sheet2");

var date1 = sheet1.getRange(1, 2, sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues(); //getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
var date2 = sheet2.getRange(1, 2, sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < date1.length; i++){
      test = sheet2.getRange(i+1, 2).getValue()
      test1 = sheet1.getRange(i+1, 2).getValue()
      if (test != test1 ) {
  var data1 = sheet1.getRange(i+1,2).getValue();
  var data2 = sheet1.getRange(i+1,3).getValues();
  var data3 = sheet1.getRange(i+1,4).getValue();
  sheet2.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(data1);
  sheet2.getRange(i+1, 3).setValue(data2);
  sheet2.getRange(i+1, 4).setValue(data3);
    }
  }
}
```